# get processes icon mfc c++

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, process, listctrl

I am making a Process-Viewer like app. in windows which displays all the processes currently running in a CListCtrl . Now i want to get the icons of the processes and show them to the listCtrl.
please help me how can i do that ??
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this using any of the following methods:

- The [ExtractAssociatedIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.
- The [SHGetFileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762179%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) shell function
- The [IExtractIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761854%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) shell interface
- The [ExtractIconEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function

Of these, the SHGetFileInfo may be the easiest.